# How do you use an array formula to calculate a running total that decreases as you move up rows?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum

When an employee works overtime for a client, we allocate those hours to the client's most recent shift (farthest row down for that employee), and then allocate the remaining OT **up** the rows.  Column D lists total hours to allocate.  Column E is a formula for OT hours available; I am trying to convert Col E to an array, but am running into a circular dependency error:

Formula that works

```
=IF(D2>0,D2,E3-C3)
```

Array formula that results in a circular dependency error:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D>0,D2:D,E3:E-C3:C))
```

I do not want to enable iterative calculations, as my sheet is about two thousand rows.  I have read *cumulative sum* [posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/cumulative-sum-without-script/46100#46100) that incorporate MMULT and ROW, or SUMIF and ROW into the ARRAYFORMULA function, but I cannot figure out how to cumulatively decrease a number as it moves **up** rows.

[image]

[Here is a link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-n04YjwoDPIm-HZ8bkYZPvjOJGyxJPyXp91FO3uOW3U/edit#gid=0)
Thank you.

Comment: For me your formula  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D>0,D2:D,E3:E-C3:C))` is working fine and it outputs the same as column E. What is exaclty the problem you are having?

Comment: @Raserhin. Thanks.  When I enter the array formula in Col E, I get this message: "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings."  I could enter the formula in another Col, but then I still have Col E with formulas in each row, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: are negative values importtant too?

Comment: @player0.  Thanks for asking.  No, negative values are not necessary. Col F will result in the same answer if Col E is 0, negative, or blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a new tab called MK.Help and put this formula in E2.  If i understand what you're going for, i think it'll work?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*(ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))),D2:D-C2:C)+C2:C)
```

Comment: I edited the formula a little in the sheet so it only displays when there is a positive number. -mpk

Comment: Thank you!  I am new to using MMULT in this way.  I appreciate you answering this!